# Big Query SQL concatenating or linking values in piped strings or arrays of strings

Tags: sql, arrays, string, google-bigquery, concatenation

I have two fields in a big BQ table.  Both fields are strings.  Both strings are formatted to represent several values separated by pipes, the same number of values in each string.  I need to associate each value in the first set with each value in the second set.  For example:

```
id   names     nums

x    "a|b|c"   "3|9|5"
y    "d"       "1"
z    "e|f"     "4|7"
```

I need to come out with a result like:

```
x,a,3
x,b,9
x,c,5
y,d,1
z,e,4
z,f,7
```

The second input string is a sequence of numbers but I don't mind if this comes out as numeric or string (I'll figure out the casting).
Seems obvious I need to use split() at some point can convert the strings to arrays, but how can I concatenate the arrays from left to right rather than lenght-wise?
I know I can use a double unnest with an index and select only where the indexes are equal, however I don't want to use this method because it makes the already large input table massive (before selecting the equal indexes).
Thanks for any thoughts!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one method that generates a series of subscripts and uses arrays to extract the values:

```
select id, split(names, '|')[safe_ordinal(n)] as names, 
       split(nums, '|')[safe_ordinal(n)] as nums
from (select 'x' as id, 'a|b|c' as names, '3|9|5' as nums union all
      select 'y', 'd', '1' union all
      select 'z', 'e|f', '4|7'
     ) t cross join
     unnest(generate_array(1, array_length(split(names, '|')))) as n;
```

This uses the length of `names` to determine how many values there are.

Comment: This looks great thanks - certainly works on the example, don't see why it wouldn't work in practice.

Answer (score 0):

Alternative option for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
SELECT id, name, num
FROM `project.dataset.table`,
UNNEST(SPLIT(names, '|')) name WITH OFFSET
JOIN UNNEST(SPLIT(nums, '|')) num WITH OFFSET
USING(OFFSET)
```

If apply to sample data in your question as in below example

```
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
  SELECT 'x' id, 'a|b|c' names, '3|9|5' nums UNION ALL
  SELECT 'y', 'd', '1' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'z', 'e|f', '4|7' 
)
SELECT id, name, num
FROM `project.dataset.table`,
UNNEST(SPLIT(names, '|')) name WITH OFFSET
JOIN UNNEST(SPLIT(nums, '|')) num WITH OFFSET
USING(OFFSET)
```

result is

```
Row id  name    num  
1   x   a       3    
2   x   b       9    
3   x   c       5    
4   y   d       1    
5   z   e       4    
6   z   f       7
```

Above can be refactored to use UDF so the main query gets simple and readable - as in below example

```
#standardSQL
CREATE TEMP FUNCTION xxx(arr1 ANY TYPE, arr2 ANY TYPE) 
RETURNS ARRAY<STRUCT<name STRING, num STRING>> AS (
ARRAY(
  SELECT AS STRUCT el1, el2
  FROM UNNEST(SPLIT(arr1, '|')) el1 WITH OFFSET
  JOIN UNNEST(SPLIT(arr2, '|')) el2 WITH OFFSET
  USING(OFFSET)
));
SELECT id, x.*
FROM `project.dataset.table`, UNNEST(xxx(names, nums)) x
```

obviously with the same output